# How to modify rows of 2D numpy arrays individually

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 2D arrays and I would like to normalize each row of each 2D array by its mean.

I have:

```
for key, value in sorted(baseline.items()): 
  for i in baseline[str(key)]:
    i = i / np.mean(i)
```

Where:

- `baseline` is a `dict`
- `baseline[str(key)]` is a 2D numpy array
- `i` is a 1D array

`print(i)` results in the appropriately updated values, however the individual rows across `baseline.items()` do not get updated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here is a solution:

```
for i in baseline.values():
    i /= i.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Now as to why. The loop `for i in baseline[key]:` binds a view into the row of a 2D array to the name `i` at each iteration. You don't need `str(key)` because the outer loop ensures that the keys are correct. In fact, avoid transforming the keys unnecessarily to avoid surprises, like if you accidentally get an integer key.

The line `i = i / np.mean(i)` does *not* do in-place division of the array by its mean. It computes the array `i / np.mean(i)`, then rebinds the name `i` to the new array. The new array is then discarded on the next iteration.

You can fix this by re-assigning into the slice that `i` represents:

```
i[:] = i / np.mean(i)
```

Alternatively, you can perform the division in-place using the correct operator:

```
i /= np.mean(i)
```

As you can see in my solution, there is no need to iterate over the rows at all. `np.mean` is a vectorized function that can operate along any axis of an array. By setting `keepdims=True`, you ensure that the result has the right shape to be broadcasted right back over the original when you divide them.

A less flexible alternative to `i.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)` specific for 2D arrays is

```
i.mean(axis=1)[:, None]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! The solution and your detailed explanation are both extremely helpful!